# Contador de Visitas Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Bom, é o seguinte eu tenho o seguinte Código na minha app.js do meu projecto, que peguei na internet para estudar:

```
 // Servidor: app.js
 // Iniciando servidor HTTP
 var app = require('http').createServer(index)
   , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
   , fs = require('fs')
 ;
 app.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log("Servidor rodando!");
 });
 function index(req, res){
   fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data){
 res.writeHead(200);
     res.end(data);
   });
 };
 // Iniciando Socket.IO
 var visitas = 0;
 // Evento connection ocorre quando entra um novo usuário.
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
   // Incrementa o total de visitas no site.
   visitas++;
   // Envia o total de visitas para o novo usuário.
   socket.emit('visits', visitas);
   // Envia o total de visitas para os demais usuários.
   socket.broadcast.emit('visits', visitas);
   // Evento disconnect ocorre quando sai um usuário.
   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
     visitas--;
     // Atualiza o total de visitas para os demais usuários.
     socket.broadcast.emit('message', visitas);
   });
 });
```

Relativamente ao HTML, eu tenho da seguinte forma:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src=/socket.io/socket.io.js></script>
     <script>
     var socket = io('http://151.80.152.6:3000');
     socket.on('visits', function(visitas){
       document.getElementById('visitas').innerHTML = visitas;
     });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Contador de visitas online com Socket.io</p>
     <p>Número de visitas: <span id="visitas">0</span></p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

O meu problema é o seguinte: Quando alguem entra no site, as visitas vao aumentando, contudo quando alguem sai, as visitas não diminuem, ou seja é necessário dar f5, para que volte a dizer as visitas reais. Como poderei fazer, para que ao "desconectar" do site, as visitas, vão diminuindo logo. Experimentei mexer no socket.broadcoast, mas não consegui.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deves emitir um evento com o mesmo nome (também pode ser com outro mas neste contexto é mais indicado ser com o mesmo), visto que o teu lado cliente não tem nenhum evento delegado para quando recebe uma emissão chamada `message` não vai acontecer nada, altera o seguinte do lado servidor:

```
...
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   visitas--;
   socket.broadcast.emit('visits', visitas); // <-- Alterar aqui
});
...
```

Se quiseres permanecer com o nome da emissão "`message`" por parte do servidor deves então preparar o lado cliente para a receber:

```
...
socket.on('visits', function(visitas){
    document.getElementById('visitas').innerHTML = visitas;
});
socket.on('message', function(visitas){
    document.getElementById('visitas').innerHTML = visitas;
});
...
```